# Modern browsers break same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

According to this video http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=562087699610 modern browsers break same origin policy so javascript can make ajax calls to whatever domain.

Is this true?

If yes, does this mean that this will be natural/acceptable whenever necessary eg to fetch data from my partner applications?

Comment: Interesting video. Tx. May be this is a reference to `window.postMessage` that allows frames to exchange string messages even if they are not on the same domain.

Comment: Somewhere along the line I picked up "window.name/navigator.parent" or (similar) that let iFrame apps communicate with the parent? Anyone knows more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a reference to [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) ?

Comment: Didn't know about that! Maybe I should use it already for my production web applications and enforce users to use the latest browsers? =)

Answer (score 1):

Note that browsers don't enforce this policy for included scripts (the same for included images or CSS). That means that someone can cleverly dynamically add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://otherdomain/something.js"></script>
```

In order to have cross-domain data. This is possible even without using CORS.

Look at [JSONP at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Comment: Will this be deprecated in favor of CORS in the future?

Comment: I don't know, but probably not. Many people load jQuery and other JavaScript libraries from Google servers. Also, most advertisement today is based on including an external JavaScript. Thus, I believe it won't be removed anytime soon. Also note that CORS support more features than JSONP (HTTP requests other than GET, better error handling...). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing